# Quantum Algebras -- Crystal Basis/Graph

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Suppose I have a finite-dimensional irreducible $U_q(sl_2)$-module say $V$, and (L,B) is its crystal basis.

How do you find the crystal basis of the evaluation $U'$-module $V_{x=1}$? And is there a nice way to visualise the crystal graph.

How would you approach same question for $V_x$ since $V_x$ is infinite dimensional of our vector K?